# Why does the animation not work if I change pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, drupal-8

I have a Drupal 8 site with Bootstrap 3 theme.

I created a homepage with a newsfeed. Whenever there is a publication on the site, it generates a message in the newsfeed. The messages can have the status read or unread.

I want that when the `.action-flag` class is in the page, an animation is applied on the logo of the site.

The CSS and JS file is included on all pages of the site.

The `.action-flag` class is only on the home page, when a message is not marked as read.

Here is the structure of my homepage :

[image]

Here is my JS code :

```
  if ($("#pills-private .action-flag").length) {
    $(".region-navigation-logo img").addClass("timeline-notification");
  };
```

Here is my CSS code :

```
@keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(138, 186, 18, 1);
    }
    70% {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(138, 186, 18, 0);
    }
    100% {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(138, 186, 18, 0);
    }
}

.region-navigation-logo img {
    height: 56px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #8aba12;
}

.timeline-notification {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(138, 186, 18, 1);
    animation: pulse 2s infinite;
}
```

Currently, the animation works very well. But only if I'm on the homepage. If I go to another page, the animation does not work anymore.

**THE PROBLEM**

It only works when I go to the homepage. I want it to work on the whole site. The goal is to notify the user that a new activity is available in their newsfeed.

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Hello, the CSS is attached globally?

Comment: Have you included the .CSS file on every page (globally as comment above) or is it only on your home page?  Do your other pages have any elements with class `timeline-notification`?

Comment: *"I want that when the "unread" class is in the page"* - neither your jquery nor your css includes `.unread`.   Please include all *relevant* code.  Have a read of [mcve].

Comment: Ok I just updated my question